# How do you JEST test a simple click with no event?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I am trying to `JEST` test these two buttons but I am currently not hitting these two functions in my `LWC Coverage`. I tried doing `btn.click()` on them and then resolving them in a `promise` to check the to see if the button was `null or not`, since the other button would show on the `UI`. But this would fail and it would return the `object` of each of the `buttons`. I know the promise syntax is wrong, atm didn't copy the code for it but just wanted to show that the `JEST` test has the `Promise` to resolve the `clicks`.

**HTML**:

```
<template if:false={isViewDesc}>
<lightning-button label='View Description' title="View Description"
                        onclick={handleClickedView} class="view-button">
                    </lightning-button>
</template>
<template if:true={isViewDesc}>
<lightning-button label='Hide Description' title="Hide Description"
                        onclick={handleClickedHide} class="hide-button">
                    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
@api isViewDesc = false

handleClickedHide(){
     this.isViewDesc = false;
}

handleClickedView(){
     this.isViewDesc = true;
}
```

**JEST Test**:

```
testedComponent.isViewDesc = false;
document.appendChild(testedComponent);
const hideInjBtn = testedComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('.hide-button');
const viewInjBtn = testedComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('.view-button');

expect(hideInjBtn).toBeNull();
expect(viewInjBtn).not.toBeNull();

viewInjBtn.click();
Promise() => {(
expect(hideInjBtn).not.toBeNull();
expect(viewInjBtn).toBeNull();
hideInjBtn.click();
     Promise() => {(
          expect(hideInjBtn).toBeNull();
          expect(viewInjBtn).not.toBeNull();
     )}
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With each click, you want to allow for the re-render to take effect. While not exactly your scenario, this example in the [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/helloConditionalRendering/__tests__/helloConditionalRendering.test.js) has the following function and comment

```js
// Helper function to wait until the microtask queue is empty. 
// This is needed for promise timing when calling imperative Apex.
async function flushPromises() {
    return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Notice the comment mentioning waiting until the microtask queue is empty. You don't just want to create a Promise, you want it to be resolved - meaning that the [re-render](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered) (which is also a microtask enqueued on the click) has finished since your interaction (in this case, a button click). My previous [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366963/setting-focus-on-conditionally-rendered-input/366973#366973) contains more information regarding this if you're interested.

In terms of your example, you can resolve the promise and chain [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#timing) to be sure your clicks that enqueued a re-render have completed.

```js
viewInjBtn.click();

return Promise.resolve()
    .then(async () => {
        expect(hideInjBtn).not.toBeNull();
        expect(viewInjBtn).toBeNull();
        hideInjBtn.click();
    })
    .then(() => {
        expect(hideInjBtn).toBeNull();
        expect(viewInjBtn).not.toBeNull();
    });
```

Comment: thank you, this was my issue. I was missing the .then on the clicks to be resolved.