# LWC issue with custom validation message

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation

In my LWC, I need an input to be required when a specific option in a radio-group is selected.

When the user clicks on the into the input directly below the **Another Amount** radio button, that option is automatically selected and the input is now required:

[image]

When I select a different option, say **Amount Due Today**, the input still displays the validation message, even though my code clears it:

[image]

When I click the **Remaining Balance** option, the validation message finally disappears:

[image]

There seems to be a lag when that validation message gets removed.  Am I clearing the custom validation message incorrectly?  Is there some other way to immediately clear the custom validation?

My code is in the following repo:  https://github.com/mikesobczak/LWC-Custom-Validation-Issue

And here:

payment.html

```html
<template>
    
    <div class="paymentArea">
    
        <div class="slds-var-m-bottom_medium slds-card__header-title">{labels.component.paymentHeader}</div>

            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-var-m-bottom_small">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-nowrap">
                    {labels.component.amountToPay}
                </div>

                <div class="slds-col">
                    <lightning-radio-group
                        name="amountToPay"
                        label={labels.component.amountToPay}
                        variant="label-hidden"
                        options={amountToPayOptions}
                        value={amountToPaySelection}
                        type="radio"
                        onchange={handleAmountToPayChange}
                        class="slds-var-m-bottom_small requiredInput"
                        required>

                    </lightning-radio-group>

                    <lightning-input 
                        type="number" 
                        name="anotherAmount" 
                        label="Another Amount" 
                        variant="label-hidden" 
                        value={anotherAmount} 
                        min="1"
                        onfocus={handleAnotherAmountFocus}
                        onchange={handleAnotherAmountChange}
                        formatter="currency"
                        class="inputAmount anotherAmount requiredInput"
                        required={isAnotherAmountRequired}
                        >
                    </lightning-input>

                </div>

            </div>

    </div>

   </template>
```

payment.js

```js
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

    const ANOTHER_AMOUNT_OPTION = 'anotherAmount';
    const AMOUNT_DUE_TODAY_OPTION = 'amountDueToday';

    export default class Payment extends LightningElement {

    labels = {
        toast: {
            processingErrorTitle: 'Processing Error'
            , validationErrorTitle: 'Input Validation Error'
            , validationErrorMessage: 'Please provide values for all required fields'
        },
        component: {
            paymentHeader: 'Payment'
            , amountToPay: 'Amount to Pay'
            , amountDueToday: 'Amount Due Today '
            , remainingBalance: 'Remaining Balance '
            , anotherAmount: 'Another Amount'
        }
    }

    amountToPaySelection;
    anotherAmount;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.amountToPaySelection = AMOUNT_DUE_TODAY_OPTION
    }

    handleAmountToPayChange(event) {

        console.log('payment', 'handleAmountToPayChange()', event.detail.value);

        this.amountToPaySelection = event.detail.value;

        if(this.amountToPaySelection !== ANOTHER_AMOUNT_OPTION) {
            this.anotherAmount = undefined;

            let anotherAmountCmp = this.template.querySelector(".anotherAmount");
            anotherAmountCmp.setCustomValidity("");
            anotherAmountCmp.reportValidity();
            anotherAmountCmp.checkValidity();
        }
    }

    handleAnotherAmountChange(event) {
        const value = event.detail.value;
        this.anotherAmount = value;
    }

    handleAnotherAmountFocus(event) {
        this.amountToPaySelection = ANOTHER_AMOUNT_OPTION;
    }

    get isAnotherAmountRequired() {
        console.log('isAnotherAmountRequired()', this.amountToPaySelection);
        if(this.amountToPaySelection === ANOTHER_AMOUNT_OPTION) {
            console.log('isAnotherAmountRequired() = true');
            return true;
        }
        console.log('isAnotherAmountRequired() = false');

        return false;
    }

    get amountToPayOptions() {
        const theOptions = [];
        theOptions.push({ label: this.labels.component.amountDueToday, value: AMOUNT_DUE_TODAY_OPTION});

        let balanceLabel = this.labels.component.remainingBalance;

        theOptions.push({ label: balanceLabel, value: 'remainingBalance'});
        
        theOptions.push({ label: this.labels.component.anotherAmount, value: ANOTHER_AMOUNT_OPTION });

        return theOptions;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM lags behind the VDOM (Virtual DOM), so you do need to wait a tick before you reset the validity. No need to go crazy here, though, just do the following:

```
async handleAmountToPayChange(event) {
    this.amountToPaySelection = event.detail.value;
    const anotherAmountField = this.template.querySelector('.anotherAmount');
    if(this.amountToPaySelection !== ANOTHER_AMOUNT_OPTION) {
        this.anotherAmount = undefined;
        await Promise.resolve();
        anotherAmountField.reportValidity();
    } else {
      anotherAmountField.focus();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/2p5LBOACOPMJUUwM1Hq3/src/app.js?p=stories).

Also, I'd advise against the getter, just set the property directly. That's what properties are meant for.

Comment: Excellent answer, this indeed looks cleaner! Thanks for sharing the async await way of handling this situation. :)

Comment: I have an issue with your example.  When I put the cursor into the anotherAmount field and click elsewhere, I don't see an error message appear.

Comment: My bad, I thought you had removed the required property from the input.  When I add it back, it works.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak I did edit it, it was missing a line of code on focus. It should befixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the issue with [conditional rendering](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366963/setting-focus-on-conditionally-rendered-input) because the report validity finishes before the template renders.

You may use a [timeout with 0 milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/1023542) to execute your code after template renders.

Also you can set your message conditionally to `setCustomValidity` function, modifying the function as below seems to be working fine:

```js
handleAmountToPayChange(event) {
    console.log("payment", "handleAmountToPayChange()", event.detail.value);

    this.amountToPaySelection = event.detail.value;

    this.anotherAmount = undefined;
    let message = "";
    if (this.amountToPaySelection === ANOTHER_AMOUNT_OPTION) {
        message = "Complete this field.";
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation
    setTimeout(() => {
        const anotherAmountCmp =
            this.template.querySelector(".anotherAmount");
        anotherAmountCmp.setCustomValidity(message);
        anotherAmountCmp.reportValidity();
    }, 0);
}
```

Code in action: [webcomponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/1yDGoBRyHE0yxe2XtnUr).

Note: [webcomponents.dev/create/lwc](https://webcomponents.dev/create/lwc) is handy for sharing LWC code. :)

Comment: It is recommended not to use setTimeout, per [@lwc/no-async-operation](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/blob/master/docs/rules/no-async-operation.md). You can instead use an await statement.